# Why did the Warlock Lord have the face of Allanon?

Tags: character-similarity, shannara-chronicles

In The Shannara Chronicles the Warlock Lord had the same face as Allanon. He was also a druid. So why did he have the same face as Allanon? Was he related in any way to Allanon, like the teacher or master ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not seen the show myself, but I found [this](https://screenrant.com/shannara-chronicles-season-2-finale-video/) on Screenrant:

> In a surprising twist, the Warlock Lord took the human form of Manu Bennett's Allanon, since the ritual was performed using Allanon's blood.